# How do I get a list of all of the elements of a certain type in a document?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I have an MXML component and I'd like to get an array of all the elements of a specific type but I don't think this functionality is built into Flex.

For example, I would like to get all "Label" and all "HGroup" components in a document.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick:

```
    /**
     * Gets the elements by type
     * */
    public function getElementsByType(container:IVisualElementContainer, type:Class, elements:Array = null):Array {
        if (elements==null) elements = [];

        for (var i:int;i<container.numElements;i++) {
            var element:IVisualElement = container.getElementAt(i);

            if (element is type) {
                elements.push(element);
            }
            if (element is IVisualElementContainer) {
                getElementsByType(element as IVisualElementContainer, type, elements);
            }
        }

        return elements;
    }
```